# Testing reducers with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

This is the file I'm testing:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import auth from './auth';

export default combineReducers({
auth
});
```

This is my code to test:

```
 import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
 import * as api from '../../utilities/synergy-api';
 import { combineReducers } from 'redux';  
 import auth from '../auth';
 import * as types from '../../actions/types';
 import * as actions from '../../actions/authActions';

 const middlewares = [thunk];
 const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);


 test('combineReducers', () => {
 expect(actions.auth).toBe('auth');
 });
```

I'm getting an error saying that a string is expected, but undefined is being received. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: what are your filenames...

Answer (score 0):

`import * as actions from '../../actions/authActions';`

Should be:

`import actions from '../../actions/authActions';`